# How to update source srcset with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery how can I update the image in the source srcset below? I want to replace:

```
/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg
```

with:

```
/media/675138/rhondda-wales-istock_000010865871large.jpg
```

I also want to keep the image parameters the same i.e.

```
?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1920&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 1430px
```

How can I do that?

```
<div class="e-image">
    <picture>
        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1920&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 1430px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1920&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1200&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 991px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=991&amp;height=400&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 767px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=767&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 500px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=767&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 0px)">
        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img alt="">
    </picture>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```js
  $('.e-image picture source').each(function(){
   var cutent_srcset=$(this).attr('srcset');
   cutent_srcset=cutent_srcset.replace('/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg','/media/675138/rhondda-wales-istock_000010865871large.jpg');
   $(this).attr('srcset', cutent_srcset);
    //for console output only
    console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="e-image">
    <picture>
        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1920&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 1430px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1920&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1200&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 991px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=991&amp;height=400&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 767px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=767&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 500px)">
        <source srcset="/media/674122/china-consumerism-tan-pu-hui.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=767&amp;height=700&amp;rnd=131388132090000000" media="(min-width: 0px)">
        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img alt="">
    </picture>
</div>
```